# Is there a way to automatically download KnightVision games from a chess blog?

Tags: pgn

Taking as an example, this blog: http://wellingtonchess2012.blogspot.com/.

I can download the games manually by going to each game, clicking on "KVChess V2.31" in the bottom left corner, which then directs me to [a link like this](http://kvchess.com/publish.html?pgndata=%5BEvent%20%22%3F%22%5D%20%5BSite%20%22%3F%22%5D%20%5BDate%20%222014.12.12%22%5D%20%5BRound%20%22%3F%22%5D%20%5BWhite%20%22Croad%2C%20Nic%22%5D%20%5BBlack%20%22Nijman%2C%20Brian%22%5D%20%5BResult%20%220-1%22%5D%20%201.%20d4%20e6%202.%20Nf3%20b6%203.%20g3%20Bb7%204.%20Bg2%20c5%205.%20O-O%20Nf6%206.%20c4%20cxd4%207.%20Qxd4%20Bc5%208.%20Qf4%20h6%209.%20Nc3%20Nc6%2010.%20b3%20Ne7%2011.%20Bb2%20Ng6%2012.%20Qd2%20O-O%2013.%20Rad1%20Qe7%2014.%20Qc1%20Rac8%2015.%20Na4%20d5%20%2815...%20Bc6%20%7B%20is%20safer%7D%20%29%2016.%20Nxc5%20bxc5%2017.%20Rfe1%20Rfd8%2018.%20Ne5%20Nxe5%2019.%20Bxe5%20Ne8%2020.%20e3%20dxc4%2021.%20Bxb7%20Qxb7%2022.%20Qxc4%20Rd5%2023.%20Rxd5%20exd5%2024.%20Qg4%20Rc6%2025.%20Rd1%20Re6%2026.%20Bc3%20Nf6%2027.%20Qf5%20%2827.%20Bxf6%20Rxf6%2028.%20Qh5%20Rd6%2029.%20e4%20g5%2030.%20h4%20d4%2031.%20hxg5%20Qxe4%2032.%20gxh6%20Rg6%2033.%20h7%20%20Kh8%2034.%20Qxc5%20Rxg3%20%2035.%20fxg3%20Qe3%20%2036.%20Kg2%20Qe2%20%2037.%20Kh3%20Qxd1%2038.%20Qf8%20%20Kxh7%2039.%20Qxf7%20%20Kh8%20%2410%29%2027...%20d4%20%242%20%7B%5Bright%20idea%2C%20wrong%20move%20order.%20It%20was%20better%20to%20play%20g7-g6%20first%5D%7D%20%20%2827...%20g6%20%241%2028.%20Qd3%20Ne4%2029.%20Bb2%20%2829.%20Ba1%20Kf8%20%245%2030.%20h4%20Ra6%2031.%20Qc2%20g5%20%245%2032.%20f3%20Qc7%2033.%20fxe4%20Qxg3%20%2034.%20Qg2%20Qxe3%20%2035.%20Qf2%20Qxf2%20%2036.%20Kxf2%20dxe4%20%7B%20unclear%7D%20%29%2029...%20d4%2030.%20exd4%20c4%20%241%2031.%20Qc2%20%2831.%20Qxc4%20%246%20Nd2%2032.%20Rxd2%20Re1%20%2033.%20Qf1%20Rxf1%20%2034.%20Kxf1%20Qh1%20%2035.%20Ke2%20Qe4%20%20%2410%29%20%2031...%20cxb3%2032.%20axb3%20%2832.%20Qxb3%20%244%20Rb6%29%2032...%20Qd5%2033.%20Bc1%20a5%2034.%20Qd3%20%2834.%20Bxh6%20g5%2035.%20Qc8%20%20Kh7%2036.%20Bf8%20Qxb3%29%2034...%20Nd6%20%7B%20and%20it%20is%20hard%20for%20White%20to%20make%20progress%7D%20%29%2028.%20exd4%20g6%2029.%20Qf4%20%2829.%20Qc2%20%2416%29%20%20%2829.%20Qd3%20Rd6%2030.%20Qe3%20Kh7%2031.%20d5%20Rxd5%2032.%20Rxd5%20Nxd5%2033.%20Qxc5%20Nxc3%2034.%20Qxc3%29%2029...%20Ne4%20%246%20%2829...%20Qd5%20%7B%20%5BWhite%20is%20only%20somewhat%20better%5D%7D%20%29%2030.%20Bb2%20%244%20%2830.%20Qf3%20%241%20Rf6%20%244%2031.%20dxc5%20%243%20Rxf3%2032.%20Rd8%20%20Kh7%2033.%20Rh8%23%29%2030...%20Ng5%2031.%20dxc5%20%2831.%20d5%20Nh3%20%2032.%20Kf1%20Nxf4%2033.%20dxe6%20Nxe6%29%20%2031...%20Nh3%20%2032.%20Kf1%20Qh1%23%200-1), after which I can copy-paste the PGN. However, it's very tedious to need do this game by game.

Is there some automatic way to accomplish the same goal of extracting the games?

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in next way: open browser console (I tested it under google Chrome) and past next line:

```
document.getElementsByName("flashvars")
```

Then press Enter and you'll see something like this:

```
[<param name=​"flashvars" value=​"orientation=H&tabmode=false&light=f4f4fF&dark=0072b9&bordertext=494949&headerforeground=ffffff&mtforeground=000000&mtvariations=FF0000&mtmainline=000000&mtbackground=ffffff&pgndata=[Event "Club championship 2014"]​ [Site "Wellington Chess Club"]​ [Date "2014.12.11"]​ [Round "?"]​ [White "Michael Sole"]​ [Black "Aran Mol"]​ [Result "0-1"]​  1. e4 Nc6 2. Nf3 d5 3. exd5 Qxd5 4. Nc3 Qa5 5. d4 Bg4 6. Bb5 O-O-O 7. Bxc6 bxc6 8. O-O Qh5 9. h3 Bxf3 10. Qxf3 Qxf3 11. gxf3 Nf6 12. Be3 a6 13. Ne4 e6 14. c4 h6 15. Rac1 Nd7 16. c5 f5 17. Nc3 g5 18. Rfe1 Bg7 19. Rcd1 e5 20. Ne2 f4 21. Bc1 exd4 22. Nxd4 Bxd4 23. Rxd4 Nxc5 24. Rc4 Nd3 25. Re6 Rhe8 26. Rexc6 Re1%2B 27. Kg2 Rd7 28. Rc2 Nb4 29. Bd2 Nxc2 30. Bxe1 Nxe1%2B 31. Kf1 Kb7 32. Rxh6 Nxf3 33. Rh5 Nd2%2B 34. Ke2 Ne4 35. Kf3 Re7 36. h4 Nd2%2B 37. Kg4 gxh4 38. Rxh4 f3 39. Kg3 c5 40. Rh6 Re1 41. Kf4 Re2 42. Rd6 Rxf2 43. Kf5 Re2 44. Rd3 f2 0-1">​, <param name=​"flashvars" value=​"orientation=H&tabmode=false&light=f4f4fF&dark=0072b9&bordertext=494949&headerforeground=ffffff&mtforeground=000000&mtvariations=FF0000&mtmainline=000000&mtbackground=ffffff&pgndata=[Event "?"]​ [Site "?"]​ [Date "2014.12.12"]​ [Round "?"]​ [White "Croad, Nic"]​ [Black "Nijman, Brian"]​ [Result "0-1"]​  1. d4 e6 2. Nf3 b6 3. g3 Bb7 4. Bg2 c5 5. O-O Nf6 6. c4 cxd4 7. Qxd4 Bc5 8. Qf4 h6 9. Nc3 Nc6 10. b3 Ne7 11. Bb2 Ng6 12. Qd2 O-O 13. Rad1 Qe7 14. Qc1 Rac8 15. Na4 d5 (15... Bc6 { is safer}​ )​ 16. Nxc5 bxc5 17. Rfe1 Rfd8 18. Ne5 Nxe5 19. Bxe5 Ne8 20. e3 dxc4 21. Bxb7 Qxb7 22. Qxc4 Rd5 23. Rxd5 exd5 24. Qg4 Rc6 25. Rd1 Re6 26. Bc3 Nf6 27. Qf5 (27. Bxf6 Rxf6 28. Qh5 Rd6 29. e4 g5 30. h4 d4 31. hxg5 Qxe4 32. gxh6 Rg6 33. h7%2B Kh8 34. Qxc5 Rxg3%2B 35. fxg3 Qe3%2B 36. Kg2 Qe2%2B 37. Kh3 Qxd1 38. Qf8%2B Kxh7 39. Qxf7%2B Kh8 $10)​ 27... d4 $2 {[right idea, wrong move order. It was better to play g7-g6 first]​}​  (27... g6 $1 28. Qd3 Ne4 29. Bb2 (29. Ba1 Kf8 $5 30. h4 Ra6 31. Qc2 g5 $5 32. f3 Qc7 33. fxe4 Qxg3%2B 34. Qg2 Qxe3%2B 35. Qf2 Qxf2%2B 36. Kxf2 dxe4 { unclear}​ )​ 29... d4 30. exd4 c4 $1 31. Qc2 (31. Qxc4 $6 Nd2 32. Rxd2 Re1%2B 33. Qf1 Rxf1%2B 34. Kxf1 Qh1%2B 35. Ke2 Qe4%2B $10)​  31... cxb3 32. axb3 (32. Qxb3 $4 Rb6)​ 32... Qd5 33. Bc1 a5 34. Qd3 (34. Bxh6 g5 35. Qc8%2B Kh7 36. Bf8 Qxb3)​ 34... Nd6 { and it is hard for White to make progress}​ )​ 28. exd4 g6 29. Qf4 (29. Qc2 $16)​  (29. Qd3 Rd6 30. Qe3 Kh7 31. d5 Rxd5 32. Rxd5 Nxd5 33. Qxc5 Nxc3 34. Qxc3)​ 29... Ne4 $6 (29... Qd5 { [White is only somewhat better]​}​ )​ 30. Bb2 $4 (30. Qf3 $1 Rf6 $4 31. dxc5 $3 Rxf3 32. Rd8%2B Kh7 33. Rh8#)​ 30... Ng5 31. dxc5 (31. d5 Nh3%2B 32. Kf1 Nxf4 33. dxe6 Nxe6)​  31... Nh3%2B 32. Kf1 Qh1# 0-1">​, <param name=​"flashvars" value=​"orientation=H&tabmode=false&light=f4f4fF&dark=0072b9&bordertext=494949&headerforeground=ffffff&mtforeground=000000&mtvariations=FF0000&mtmainline=000000&mtbackground=ffffff&pgndata=[Event "WCC"]​ [Site "WCC"]​ [Date "2014.11.29"]​ [Round "10"]​ [White "Nick Barr"]​ [Black "Michael Sole"]​ [Result "0-1"]​  { I was playing Nick Barr and he played the Queen’s gambit. I was expecting this since this is what happened last game. The game finished at 11:​45 and closely matched our last game. }​ 1. d4 d5 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 Nf6 { Queen’s gambit declined main-line}​ 4. cxd5 exd5 { Exchange line}​ 5. Bg5 Nbd7 6. e3 Be7 7. Bd3 O-O 8. Qc2 h6 {First non-book move.    }​ 9. Bh4 b6 {This move helps prepare for c5 and Bb7. }​ 10. Nf3 c5 {This move challenges White’s centre. }​ 11. dxc5 Nxc5 {This is a nice outpost for the Knight. }​ 12. Be2 $6 {I feel that this move is not needed as the Bishop pair is not doing much here and that a developing move would be better. This move also gives up some pressure on the e4 square.      }​ (12. Rd1)​ 12... Bb7 { Putting more pressure on e4}​ 13. Nd4 { This is a nice place for his Knight and stays here for some time}​ 13... Rc8 { Grabbing the c file}​ 14. Qd1 $6 { Again I feel that this move is not needed as the Knight was protected by the b-pawn. This move could have been spent on castling }​  (14. O-O)​ 14... Nfe4 {Getting a nice place for my knight and threatening NxNc3 and then after the recapture, Ne4 wins the c-pawn. The bishop is also under attack.  }​ 15. Bxe7 Qxe7 {I like this position for Black }​ 16. Rc1 {Stopping the loss of the c-pawn }​ 16... Nxc3 17. Rxc3 Ne4 {This gains the c-file for Black }​ 18. Rb3 {I thought about this move for around 10 minutes here deciding between Qg5 and Rc5}​ 18... Rc5 {I picked this move to wait for White to castle before moving the Queen as it is in a nice place to attack the Queenside   }​  19. O-O Rfc8 {Further marking the c-file }​ 20. f3 $5 { This is the type of move I was waiting for as this weakens his king side and gives me a target to attack.}​ 20... Nd6 21. Ra3 { Attacking the a-pawn}​ 21... a6 {Setting a trap. }​  22. Qd3 { This move gives me the very useful c4 square for my Knight}​  (22. Bxa6 Bxa6 23. Rxa6 Qxe3%2B 24. Kh1 Rc1)​ 22... Nc4 23. Rb3 Re8 { Putting pressure on e3}​ 24. Nf5 $2 Qe6 $6 {This is not the best move to win the pawn Qf6 is better. }​  (24... Qf6)​ 25. Kf2 $2 {This move does little to protect the pawn }​ 25... Bc8 { Attacking the Knight}​ 26. Nd4 $2 { This move loses the pawn.}​ 26... Qf6 27. Qd1 $2 { Losing more protection}​ 27... Qh4%2B 28. Kg1 {Losing the exchange}​ 28... Nxe3 29. Qe1 $4 { This loses the Knight}​ 29... Qxd4 30. Qf2 Nf5 $2 { While this move is winning Rc2 is better}​ 31. Rxb6 $4 { Re2 is fatal now}​ 31... Qxf2%2B $2 { Not taking the bishop}​  (31... Rxe2)​ 32. Kxf2 $2 { giving the Bishop back}​ 32... Rc2 33. Re1 Nd4 34. Rb8 Rexe2%2B 35. Rxe2 Rxe2%2B 36. Kg3 { }​ 36... Re8 {Winning for Black }​ 37. b4 Nb5 38. a4 Nc3 39. b5 Bd7 40. Rb7 Bxb5 41. axb5 axb5 {Getting rid of the pawns}​ 42. Rb6 Rc8 43. Kf2 Re8 44. g4 Kf8 45. h4 Re2%2B 46. Kg3 Ke7 47. g5 hxg5 48. hxg5 Kd7 49. Kg4 Kc7 50. Ra6 Kd7 51. Kf5 g6%2B 52. Kf6 {I played the risky move of Re6%2B giving white promotion chances}​ 52... Re6%2B 53. Rxe6 fxe6 54. Kxg6 Ke7 $2 {I played this thinking that white would play Ka6 so my king could keep up}​ 55. Kh7 $1 { This move makes promotion a sure thing}​ 55... b4 56. g6 b3 57. g7 b2 58. g8=Q {He promotes first but I promote with check }​ 58... b1=Q%2B {Now I can swap Queens and queen my other pawns }​ 59. Qg6 { If the king moves then I can still swap}​  (59. Kh6 Qh1%2B 60. Kg7 Qg1%2B)​ 59... Qxg6%2B 60. Kxg6 d4 61. f4 d3 62. f5 exf5 63. Kxf5 d2 { Black resigned here.}​ 0-1">​
```

You can easy copy this. If you need you can make some performance on this text as well. If you need more help just let me know.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just a little unsure to do once I've copied this. How can I turn the copied text into a PGN?

Comment: Please check answer, because could not put all in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Everything after parameter pgndata is pgn data (obviously))). Simplest what you can do just copy information which you retrieved into text editor and organize. For example the line which I provide in the answer after organizing will look like:
 `[<param name=​"flashvars" value=​"orientation=H&tabmode=false&light=f4f4fF&dark=0072b9&bordertext=494949&headerforeground=ffffff&mtforeground=000000&mtvariations=FF0000&mtmainline=000000&mtbackground=ffffff&pgndata=
[Event "Club championship 2014”]​
[Site "Wellington Chess Club”]​
[Date "2014.12.11"]​ [Round "?”]​
[White "Michael Sole”]​
[Black "Aran Mol”]​
[Result "0-1”]​

1. e4 Nc6 2. Nf3 d5 3. exd5 Qxd5 4. Nc3 Qa5 5. d4 Bg4 6. Bb5 O-O-O 7. Bxc6 bxc6 8. O-O Qh5 9. h3 Bxf3 10. Qxf3 Qxf3 11. gxf3 Nf6 12. Be3 a6 13. Ne4 e6 14. c4 h6 15. Rac1 Nd7 16. c5 f5 17. Nc3 g5 18. Rfe1 Bg7 19. Rcd1 e5 20. Ne2 f4 21. Bc1 exd4 22. Nxd4 Bxd4 23. Rxd4 Nxc5 24. Rc4 Nd3 25. Re6 Rhe8 26. Rexc6 Re1%2B 27. Kg2 Rd7 28. Rc2 Nb4 29. Bd2 Nxc2 30. Bxe1 Nxe1%2B 31. Kf1 Kb7 32. Rxh6 Nxf3 33. Rh5 Nd2%2B 34. Ke2 Ne4 35. Kf3 Re7 36. h4 Nd2%2B 37. Kg4 gxh4 38. Rxh4 f3 39. Kg3 c5 40. Rh6 Re1 41. Kf4 Re2 42. Rd6 Rxf2 43. Kf5 Re2 44. Rd3 f2 0-1">​, 
<param name=​"flashvars" value=​"orientation=H&tabmode=false&light=f4f4fF&dark=0072b9&bordertext=494949&headerforeground=ffffff&mtforeground=000000&mtvariations=FF0000&mtmainline=000000&mtbackground=ffffff&pgndata=
[Event "?”]​
[Site "?”]​
[Date "2014.12.12”]​
[Round "?”]​
[White "Croad, Nic”]​
[Black "Nijman, Brian”]​
[Result "0-1”]​

1. d4 e6 2. Nf3 b6 3. g3 Bb7 4. Bg2 c5 5. O-O Nf6 6. c4 cxd4 7. Qxd4 Bc5 8. Qf4 h6 9. Nc3 Nc6 10. b3 Ne7 11. Bb2 Ng6 12. Qd2 O-O 13. Rad1 Qe7 14. Qc1 Rac8 15. Na4 d5 (15... Bc6 { is safer}​ )​ 16. Nxc5 bxc5 17. Rfe1 Rfd8 18. Ne5 Nxe5 19. Bxe5 Ne8 20. e3 dxc4 21. Bxb7 Qxb7 22. Qxc4 Rd5 23. Rxd5 exd5 24. Qg4 Rc6 25. Rd1 Re6 26. Bc3 Nf6 27. Qf5 (27. Bxf6 Rxf6 28. Qh5 Rd6 29. e4 g5 30. h4 d4 31. hxg5 Qxe4 32. gxh6 Rg6 33. h7%2B Kh8 34. Qxc5 Rxg3%2B 35. fxg3 Qe3%2B 36. Kg2 Qe2%2B 37. Kh3 Qxd1 38. Qf8%2B Kxh7 39. Qxf7%2B Kh8 $10)​ 27... d4 $2 {[right idea, wrong move order. It was better to play g7-g6 first]​}​  (27... g6 $1 28. Qd3 Ne4 29. Bb2 (29. Ba1 Kf8 $5 30. h4 Ra6 31. Qc2 g5 $5 32. f3 Qc7 33. fxe4 Qxg3%2B 34. Qg2 Qxe3%2B 35. Qf2 Qxf2%2B 36. Kxf2 dxe4 { unclear}​ )​ 29... d4 30. exd4 c4 $1 31. Qc2 (31. Qxc4 $6 Nd2 32. Rxd2 Re1%2B 33. Qf1 Rxf1%2B 34. Kxf1 Qh1%2B 35. Ke2 Qe4%2B $10)​  31... cxb3 32. axb3 (32. Qxb3 $4 Rb6)​ 32... Qd5 33. Bc1 a5 34. Qd3 (34. Bxh6 g5 35. Qc8%2B Kh7 36. Bf8 Qxb3)​ 34... Nd6 { and it is hard for White to make progress}​ )​ 28. exd4 g6 29. Qf4 (29. Qc2 $16)​  (29. Qd3 Rd6 30. Qe3 Kh7 31. d5 Rxd5 32. Rxd5 Nxd5 33. Qxc5 Nxc3 34. Qxc3)​ 29... Ne4 $6 (29... Qd5 { [White is only somewhat better]​}​ )​ 30. Bb2 $4 (30. Qf3 $1 Rf6 $4 31. dxc5 $3 Rxf3 32. Rd8%2B Kh7 33. Rh8#)​ 30... Ng5 31. dxc5 (31. d5 Nh3%2B 32. Kf1 Nxf4 33. dxe6 Nxe6)​  31... Nh3%2B 32. Kf1 Qh1# 0-1">​, 
<param name=​"flashvars" value=​"orientation=H&tabmode=false&light=f4f4fF&dark=0072b9&bordertext=494949&headerforeground=ffffff&mtforeground=000000&mtvariations=FF0000&mtmainline=000000&mtbackground=ffffff&pgndata=
[Event "WCC”]​ 
[Site "WCC”]​ 
[Date "2014.11.29”]​ 
[Round "10”]​ 
[White "Nick Barr”]​ 
[Black "Michael Sole”]​ 
[Result "0-1”]​

{ I was playing Nick Barr and he played the Queen’s gambit. I was expecting this since this is what happened last game. The game finished at 11:​45 and closely matched our last game. }​ 1. d4 d5 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 Nf6 { Queen’s gambit declined main-line}​ 4. cxd5 exd5 { Exchange line}​ 5. Bg5 Nbd7 6. e3 Be7 7. Bd3 O-O 8. Qc2 h6 {First non-book move.    }​ 9. Bh4 b6 {This move helps prepare for c5 and Bb7. }​ 10. Nf3 c5 {This move challenges White’s centre. }​ 11. dxc5 Nxc5 {This is a nice outpost for the Knight. }​ 12. Be2 $6 {I feel that this move is not needed as the Bishop pair is not doing much here and that a developing move would be better. This move also gives up some pressure on the e4 square.      }​ (12. Rd1)​ 12... Bb7 { Putting more pressure on e4}​ 13. Nd4 { This is a nice place for his Knight and stays here for some time}​ 13... Rc8 { Grabbing the c file}​ 14. Qd1 $6 { Again I feel that this move is not needed as the Knight was protected by the b-pawn. This move could have been spent on castling }​  (14. O-O)​ 14... Nfe4 {Getting a nice place for my knight and threatening NxNc3 and then after the recapture, Ne4 wins the c-pawn. The bishop is also under attack.  }​ 15. Bxe7 Qxe7 {I like this position for Black }​ 16. Rc1 {Stopping the loss of the c-pawn }​ 16... Nxc3 17. Rxc3 Ne4 {This gains the c-file for Black }​ 18. Rb3 {I thought about this move for around 10 minutes here deciding between Qg5 and Rc5}​ 18... Rc5 {I picked this move to wait for White to castle before moving the Queen as it is in a nice place to attack the Queenside   }​  19. O-O Rfc8 {Further marking the c-file }​ 20. f3 $5 { This is the type of move I was waiting for as this weakens his king side and gives me a target to attack.}​ 20... Nd6 21. Ra3 { Attacking the a-pawn}​ 21... a6 {Setting a trap. }​  22. Qd3 { This move gives me the very useful c4 square for my Knight}​  (22. Bxa6 Bxa6 23. Rxa6 Qxe3%2B 24. Kh1 Rc1)​ 22... Nc4 23. Rb3 Re8 { Putting pressure on e3}​ 24. Nf5 $2 Qe6 $6 {This is not the best move to win the pawn Qf6 is better. }​  (24... Qf6)​ 25. Kf2 $2 {This move does little to protect the pawn }​ 25... Bc8 { Attacking the Knight}​ 26. Nd4 $2 { This move loses the pawn.}​ 26... Qf6 27. Qd1 $2 { Losing more protection}​ 27... Qh4%2B 28. Kg1 {Losing the exchange}​ 28... Nxe3 29. Qe1 $4 { This loses the Knight}​ 29... Qxd4 30. Qf2 Nf5 $2 { While this move is winning Rc2 is better}​ 31. Rxb6 $4 { Re2 is fatal now}​ 31... Qxf2%2B $2 { Not taking the bishop}​  (31... Rxe2)​ 32. Kxf2 $2 { giving the Bishop back}​ 32... Rc2 33. Re1 Nd4 34. Rb8 Rexe2%2B 35. Rxe2 Rxe2%2B 36. Kg3 { }​ 36... Re8 {Winning for Black }​ 37. b4 Nb5 38. a4 Nc3 39. b5 Bd7 40. Rb7 Bxb5 41. axb5 axb5 {Getting rid of the pawns}​ 42. Rb6 Rc8 43. Kf2 Re8 44. g4 Kf8 45. h4 Re2%2B 46. Kg3 Ke7 47. g5 hxg5 48. hxg5 Kd7 49. Kg4 Kc7 50. Ra6 Kd7 51. Kf5 g6%2B 52. Kf6 {I played the risky move of Re6%2B giving white promotion chances}​ 52... Re6%2B 53. Rxe6 fxe6 54. Kxg6 Ke7 $2 {I played this thinking that white would play Ka6 so my king could keep up}​ 55. Kh7 $1 { This move makes promotion a sure thing}​ 55... b4 56. g6 b3 57. g7 b2 58. g8=Q {He promotes first but I promote with check }​ 58... b1=Q%2B {Now I can swap Queens and queen my other pawns }​ 59. Qg6 { If the king moves then I can still swap}​  (59. Kh6 Qh1%2B 60. Kg7 Qg1%2B)​ 59... Qxg6%2B 60. Kxg6 d4 61. f4 d3 62. f5 exf5 63. Kxf5 d2 { Black resigned here.}​ 0-1">​`